# Adding style sheet to feature

Tags: visual-studio, feature, visual-web-part

I have created a feature in sharepoint 2010.  The feature has a visual web part (sandboxed), the web part has controls etc.

I have added some styles to the web part.  How do i upload the stylesheet to sharepoint 2010? This must be done via visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use **CustomAction** and **ScriptBlock**, it's not pretty, but it does work.
Add a normal **Module** and add this:

```
<CustomAction Location="ScriptLink" Sequence="SOME NUMER"
  ScriptBlock=";(function(){var l=document.createElement('link');l.rel='stylesheet';l.href='PATH TO CSS';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(l);})();" />
```

Replace *SOME NUMBER* and *PATH TO CSS* with the values you need.

**Update**

For actually placing the CSS file on server you could use the same Module.

```
<Module Name="YourModule">
  <File Path="YourModule\path\css\style.css" Url="path/css/style.css" />
</Module>
```

You could also set `Type="GhostableInLibrary"` and `IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE"` but since it's a Sandboxed Solution I don't think that would matter [reference needed].

Comment: Thanks. i know how to reference the stylesheet.  What i need to know is how do i upload it to sharepoint via a visual studio feature?

Comment: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding. You can do it in the module as I mentioned in the answer. Let me update

Comment: Thanks for accepting :)  Just a note, I prefer to add scripts and stylesheets in a **Module** because then I know they will be referenced only once (ish). If you reference directly in your visual Web Part then adding the same Web Part twice to a page might cause havoc (for scripts).

Comment: +1 - never thinked of adding the script with a custom action. Always used a delegate control with a "injector" user control.